# Windows Forms 3.5 how to scroll a DataGridView vertically via code

Tags: datagridview

The client wants to be able to type a letter and have the system scroll the DataGridView such that the first row with a cell that matched the letter will scroll to the top of the DataGridView

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how you will be able to lookup efficiently for the getting the row which matches the letter you have. But you can have a look at these properties which would help you setting the focus

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex //set the rowindex
```

In case you have a horizontal scroll also set this value

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex
```

I believe you would be looping through, so you should be able to set these values and again set the **CurrentCell** as the one you found.

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe it will work but I haven't gotten a chance to try it